# Iterating over an Array to find a string value

Tags: java

```
public void addSampleData(){
    userList.add(new User("n45","sfdsf","sfgfsg"));
```

I want to iterate through the array and to be able to identify and remove the object based on its string value i.e "sfdsf" rather than its position in the arraylist.

Comment: How did you defined User class?

Comment: ArrayList<User> userList;

Comment: I need definition of User class. i could make out what userlist would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array simply using a `for` loop (either a basic one or an enhanced loop):

```
for (User user : userList) {
  // Do whatever you want on the item in the current iterator position
}
```

If you want to identify the object and potentially compare it to other objects, you have to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. (Better on the subject on [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/))

If you are only considering the field you mentioned, *sfdsf*, to be your `User` identifier, you can then use that instance variable in your comparison; e.g:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
  if ("sfdsf".equals(user.getYourField())) { // Note that getYourField refers to your subject field accessor
    userList.remove(i); // Remove the item if it matches the criteria
  }
}
```